# Need some perspective on my custom AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I recently started fiddling with AppleScript, but I can't seem to get my script to work. However, I do not get any errors. The scripts executes and 'nothing' happens.

```
tell application "Finder"
set theWin to window 1
set thePath to (POSIX path of (target of theWin as alias))
copy file "Macintosh HD:Users:thijmendam:Documents:NieuwBestandSource:Naamloos.pages" to thePath
end tell
```

What I want to do, is move the file Naamloos.pages to the current opened Finder window. This works fine if I want to copy it to a folder. However if I use thePath, 'nothing' happens.
In example, the following script does work:

```
'tell application "Finder"
set theWin to window 1
set thePath to (POSIX path of (target of theWin as alias))
copy file "Macintosh HD:Users:thijmendam:Documents:NieuwBestandSource:Naamloos.pages" to folder "this:is:a:destination:folder"
end tell
```

Obviously this is not what I want to achieve. I just don't know how to copy the file to thePath. Can anyone help me out?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to use posix path just remove that

here is an example

```
tell application "Finder"
set afile to (choose file) as alias
set theWin to window 1
set thePath to (target of theWin as alias)
copy file afile to folder thePath
```

end tell

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked. Saved me another headache :-)

Comment: you're welcome Posix path is good if you are trying to run shell commands

Comment: Also, is it possible to rename the file to a certain name that I have to specify in a popup textbox or something like that?

Comment: yes it is you'll want to get the text returned from the display dialog into a variable and tac that on to the end of thePath

Comment: Thanks both. 
I've got this to set my custom string to a variable. How can I apply it to the file I want to copy?

set theName to the text returned of 
  (display dialog "Specify Filename" default answer "")

Also I don't want to extension .pages to be removed

Comment: Well copy seems to work just as well, and yes omitting the firs alias is ok

Answer (score 0):

First of all the proper command to copy files in the Finder is `duplicate`.

The Finder accepts only HFS paths (colon separated)

To make the script portable it's recommended to use relative paths like `path to documents folder`

```
set documentsFolder to path to documents folder as text

set newName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a Name" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2)

if newName does not end with ".pages" the set newName to newName & ".pages"

tell application "Finder"
    set theWin to window 1
    set thePath to target of theWin as alias
    set duplicatedFile to duplicate file (documentsFolder & "NieuwBestandSource:Naamloos.pages") to thePath
    set name of duplicatedFile to newName
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you; works flawlessly. Also, do you know a way to give it a custom name using a dialoge box before duplicating my file?

Comment: One more thing: can the name of the file be changed before the file is duplicated? Because if there is a naamloos.pages file in the folder I want to copy to, the process gets interrupted and the script won't work.

Comment: If you want to overwrite an existing file add `with replacing` at the end of the `duplicate` line. Renaming the file before being duplicated is not possible.